# Jenkins + Grunt + Git Deployment (Newbie help)

Tags: git, angularjs, github, jenkins, gruntjs

I am hoping some of you guys can point me in the right direction. I am new to deployment and would like some help. I have googled around but have not been able to get the answers that would work for me.

Here is what I have.

I am developing an angularjs app. I am running grunt and karma and I would like some help on the deployment side.

The way I have done it before is the following.

```
#!/bin/bash
#git push --mirror git@github.com:<group>/<repo>.git
echo "pushing to repo"
git push --mirror git@<location>:<group>/<repo>.git
curl http://jenkins.<something.com>/git/notifyCommit? 
url=git@127.0.0.1:<group>/<repo>.git
```

1. Local repo on laptop pushes to local server.
2. Local server receives the push.
3. Local server has an update hook enabled that gets used.
4. Git Hook in local server mirrors the repo to a server that has jenkins installed on it. It also notifies jenkins.
5. Server with jenkins receives the cahanges. Jenkins in notified via the hook on the local server.
6. Jenkins runs a bash script that contains a git diff process and FTPs the files that changed.

That is all good and dandy; However, I am now developing an app that requires grunt so that it can be built and i do not know where to start with jenkins.

Here is my plan and im hoping you guys can guide me further:

1. Same process as before only this time we will be ignoring the dist/ folder in the local machine which contains what grunt builds according to the changes you have made on the code.
2. Code is pushed to local server.
3. local server mirrors repo to jenkin's server. Jenkins also gets notified.
4. Grunt is called on the jenkins server to be ran depending on the changes pushed to that server.
5. Jenkins pushes the dist/ folder only to whatever server i want.

My question is regarding, how to run grunt using jenkins. And how to only distribute the dist/ folder using jenkins. I have installed grunt on the server that jenkins is on but that is as far as i have gone. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar application setup I haven't yet worked on the CI part of it yet but through Jenkins you can run grunt as a Execute windows batch command and then use send files to windows share(I am not sure about non-windows env) in Jenkins to copy across your dist folder to the "server". Hope this helps a bit

Update: 
I have finally worked on the CI part now and this is what I did on the Jenkins using "Execute Windows Batch command" option

```
npm install
bower install
grunt build --force
xcopy Website\dist \\Destination-Servier\Website
```

Easy?